# Unable to increase PageSize

Tags: ignite

In the config.xml, the following lines sets the "Page Size".

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
  <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">

      <!-- Set the page size to 8 KB -->
      <property name="pageSize" value="8192"/>
    </bean>
  </property>

  <!--- Additional settings ---->
</bean>
```

As per my understanding, the data entered by the client, is stored in 'pages' in the memory, therefore, if I increase the page-size, more number of key-value pairs can be accommodated in the same page. I was thinking that, this size might affect the throughput therefore I wanted to increase the size, however, I'm unable to do so. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to instantiate configuration from Spring XML: ./../../../config/config.xml
```

Ignite seems to be accepting only 8 KB as the value of page Size. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, Ignite allows changing pageSize, but you need to remember that
Page size must be a power of 2 and it must be between 1kB and 16kB(it was found that these values are best for performance perspective).

Anyway, Ignite always shows the full exception, I don't know why you don't see it in the logs, maybe you have wrong logs configuration